# Multi Dimensional Associative Array of Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, arguments

So I have the following code:

```
$options = array(
    'navigation' => array(
        'page_title' => 'test',
        'menu_title' => 'test_title',
        'capabillity' => '',
        'menu_slug' => '',
        'function' => '',
        'icon_url' => '',
        'position' => '',
        'sub_menues' => array(
            array(
                'page_title' => 'test',
                'menu_title' => 'test_title',
                'menu_slug' => 'bla'
            ), 
            array(
                'page_title' => 'apples',
                'menu_title' => 'test_apples',
            ), // Set of Navigations
        )
    ),
    'settings' => array(
        array(
            'option_group' => 'bla',
            'option_name' => '',
            'sanitize_call_back' => ''
        )
    ),
    'core_template' => 'path/to/admin/template.phtml'
);

foreach($options as $setting=>$option){
    if($setting == 'navigation' && is_array($option)){
        foreach($option as $k=>$v){
            if(is_array($v)){
                foreach($v as $sub_menu){
                    foreach($sub_menu as $sk=>$sv){
                        if(isset($sub_menu[$sk])){
                            echo $sub_menu['menu_slug'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(isset($option[$k])){
                echo $option['page_title'];
            }
        }
    }

    if($setting == 'settings' && is_array($option)){
        foreach($option as $settings_options){
            foreach($settings_options as $sk => $sv){
                if(isset($settings_options[$sk])){
                    echo $settings_options['option_group'];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if($setting = 'core_template'){
        echo $options['core_template'];
    }
}
```

Which, yes is a mess and needs to be refactored, works UNTIL you throw in a variable that doesn't exist. a good way to see this:

```
echo $sub_menu['menu_slug'];
```

now menu_slug exists in navigation/sub_menues/[0] array, but not in [1]array.

The typical way to fix this is:

```
if(isset($sub_menu['menu_slug'])){ // do something }
```

How ever as you can see from the navigation array, there is going to be **A LOT** of *if is set do this, else do that.* and I am looking for a cleaner and neater way where I can just do $sub_menu['something'] and it automatically checks to see if something exists and if so, returns its value, if NOT do nothing, just ignore it.

Now I have the right idea, where I do *if is set $sub_menu[$sk]* and then I could do:

```
echo $sub_menu[$sk];
```

the problem is I am calling a function in here that takes in arguments, the arguments are the values of the key, hence why I have to do $sub_menu['menu_slug'] for example.

**So my question is:**

How do I do something like:

```
some_function_call($sub_menu['menu_slug']);
```

with out having to do:

```
if(isset($sub_menu['menu_slug']) && isset($sub_menu['page_title']) /*...and so on...*/){
    some_function_call($sub_menu['menu_slug'], $sub_menu['page_title'] /*..and so on...*/);
}
```

**The catch?** - some options, such as (say for example) menu slug, might be optional.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you're keys are unique relatively to all levels, you could do:

```
array_walk_recursive($options, function($value, $key){
  if($value && in_array($key, array('menu_slug', 'page_title', 'option_group', 'core_template')))
    print $value;  
});
```

:)

But I assume that your real purpose is to wrap this text in HTML strings, so you should use `switch` instead of my `if` statement and print whatever you want. If you need to print the stuff in a certain order, use a temporary array to store the output you generate, and print it after you're done.

Comment: I'm using that to decide what values to print. Anyway, did you try it?