# implode logic not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

So I am building off of [this question about multidimensional associative array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793148/multi-dimensional-associative-array-of-arrays/14793314#comment20716892_14793314). and what I came up with is a really simple and easy way to solve my problem. The following array:

```
$options = array(
    'navigation' => array(
        'page_title' => __('Aisis', 'aisis'),
        'menu_title' => __('Aisis', 'aisis'),
        'capabillity' => 'edit_themes',
        'menu_slug' => 'aisis-core-options',
        'function' => 'some_function',
        'icon_url' => '',
        'position' => '',
        'sub_menues' => array(
            array(
                'page_title' => __('Aisis', 'aisis'),
                'menu_title' => __('Aisis', 'aisis'),
                'capabillity' => 'edit_themes',
                'menu_slug' => 'aisis-core-options',
                'function' => 'some_function',
            ), 
            array(
                'page_title' => __('Aisis', 'aisis'),
                'menu_title' => __('Aisis', 'aisis'),
                'capabillity' => 'edit_themes',
                'menu_slug' => 'aisis-core-options',
                'function' => 'some_function',
            ), 
        )
    ),
    'settings' => array(
        array(
            'option_group' => 'bla',
            'option_name' => '',
            'sanitize_call_back' => ''
        )
    ),
    'core_template' => 'path/to/admin/template.phtml'
);
```

Is then processed as such:

```
foreach($options as $settings=>$option){
    if($setting = 'navigation' && is_array($option)){
        foreach($option as $option_key=>$option_value){
            var_dump($option);
            if(!is_array($option_value)){
                echo implode(',', $option);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is:

in the last if statement I am stating, or at least I think I am, as long as the value for the key in the $options['navigation'] is NOT an array, implode the array and return the values. It all works as expected, accept it gives me *"Array to string conversion"* which it "shouldn't" due to the if statement.

So my simple question is:

**How do I implode $options['navigation'] as long as the value of a key is not an array?**

I thought I was on the right track....

Also, on that note, when I var_dump($option_values) I see the other arrays, so not only do I see 'sub_menues' but I also see 'settings' array

I thought my logic was sound with:

*if the key is navigation, do this.*

Essentially I am having a scope issue with arrays in this case, so how do I make it ONLY look at the key => values and any additional arrays with in the $options['navigation'] instead of with in $options?

Comment: `implode()` explicitly works on arrays... if the key is NOT an array you shouldnt use `implode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct solution building off of Kolink's solution:

```
$temp_array = array();
if( is_array($options['navigation'])) {
    foreach($options['navigation'] as $value) {
        if(!is_array($value)){
            $temp_array[] = $value;
        }
    }

    echo implode(',', $temp_array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` instead of `=` to compare values.

EDIT: That said, why are you using a `foreach` if you're only interested in one key?

```
if( is_array($options['navigation'])) {
    foreach($options['navigation'] as $value) {
        if( is_array($value)) echo implode(",",$value);
    }
}
```

Comment: because if the value of a key is NOT an array, implode, else implode.